# Cloud Foundry local - droplet not found

Tags: cloud-foundry, droplet

I have my cf local running.
First I pull my droplet in my Folder `/Development/myProject`

```
cf local pull myProjekt
```

than I want to run my cf local with

```
cf local run myProject -f myProject
```

but than an error occures with

```
Error: open ./myProject.droplet: no such file or directory
```

Than I thought I have to give the complete path to the droplet, although it is in the current folder where I run my

```
cf local run ...
```

Than I tried

```
cf local run myProject -f myProject -d ~/Development/myProject
```

but the same error occures.
Have someone an idea how to run it correctly?
THANKS for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the `-f` flag. That is doing something else. Just remove it.

Run: `cf local pull myProject` followed by `cf local run myProject`

The name to the `pull` command should match the name to the `run` command. In your case, there's a difference: `myProjekt` vs `myProject`.

If you run `cf local --help` you can get more help. Here's the snippet for `run`.

```
RUN OPTIONS:
   run <name>     Run a droplet with the configuration specified in local.yml.
                     Droplet filename: <name>.droplet

   -i <ip>        Listen on the specified interface IP
                     Default: localhost
   -p <port>      Listen on the specified port
                     Default: (arbitrary free port)
   -d <dir>       Replace the app directory with the specified directory.
                     The app directory from the droplet is ignored.
                     Default: (not mounted)
   -w             When used with -d, restart the app when the contents of the
                     specified directory are changed.
                     Default: false, Invalid: with -t, without -d
   -t             Start a shell (Bash) with the same environment as the app.
                     Default: false, Invalid: with -w
   -s <app>       Use the service bindings from the specified remote CF app
                     instead of the service bindings in local.yml.
                     Default: (uses local.yml or app provided by -f)
   -f <app>       Tunnel service connections through the specified remote CF
                     app. This re-writes the service bindings in the container
                     environment in order to use the tunnel. The service
                     bindings from the specified app will be used if -s is not
                     also passed.
                     Default: (uses local.yml)
```